# Kubernetes: topologySpreadConstraint not respected

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have two nodes matching cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=preemt2, but somehow my Deployment of two replicas does not get distributed to both nodes. They are always scheduled on one of the two nodes, and I cannot get behind the reason.

```
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
              - key: cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool
                operator: In
                values:
                  - preemt2
  topologySpreadConstraints:
   - maxSkew: 1
     topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
     whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
     labelSelector:
       matchLabels:
         app: my-deployment
```

Comment: Pretty weird indeed. Have you tried to remove your topologySpreadConstraint? (that's the affinity rule that's not observed, but your spread constraint allows for a drift of one / the maxSkew value.... could this be a bug in the scheduler, while aggregating those placement rules?). What version of Kubernetes are you running?

Comment: @SYN I was running the Deployment without the constraint all the time, but the scheduler placed the pods on one node. That's why I tried it with the constraint. I am using 1.18.20-gke.901.

Comment: I think you will need to upgrade to 1.19 or later.  Also, you are probably better off using pod anti-affinity here rather than topology spread constraints.

Comment: @GariSingh what happens with antiAffinity constraints if I have e.g. 10 replicas and 2 nodes? Will it place 5 pods on one node and 5 on the other? (I.e. can this be achieved with antiAffinity alone?)

Comment: @MarcelloRomani - in that case, you'd have to use something like topologySpreadConstraints

Comment: @Ana did you find a solution? I have the same problem on k8s 1.23